# What are the benefits of async/await in ASP.NET requests?

Tags: c#, performance, async-await

I'm trying to understand the performance benefits of using async/await C# code when you know you're already inside a separate thread (ie an ASP.NET Core endpoint).

Lets assume we have following C# code inside an ASP.NET Core API:

```
//This is the ASP.NET Core endpoint
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
      await CallAllAsync();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> CallAllAsync()
{
      await CallBAsync();
      await CallCAsync();
      await CallDAsync();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> CallBAsync()
{
      await SomeDatabaseCallAsync();
}
public async Task<ActionResult> CallCAsync()
{
      await SomeHttpCallAsync();
}
public async Task<ActionResult> CallDAsync()
{
      await SomeFileSaveAsync();
}
```

My understanding of how the above works is:

1. When an HTTP request comes in to the ASP.NET Core endpoint, a new thread is taken from the thread pool and used to run the code for that call. Lets call this thread `Thread_Get`.
2. When `await CallAllAsync()` is called, a Task instance is taken from a Task pool and the code inside `CallAllAsync()` is run. Lets say the thread for that task is `Thread_All`. This pauses the parent`Thread_Get` and it will not run until `Thread_All` is completed.
3. Because the calls inside `CallAllAsync()` are sequential (ie, not using a `Task.WhenAll()`), they will all run one after another. So the same process will happen here. A Task is taken from the task pool, the code is `CallBAsync()` is run inside it, which uses another Task/Thread to run `SomeDatabaseCallAsync()`. Once those are done, the same then happens for `CallCAsync()` and `CallDAsync()`.

My question is, since all of this run inside a new thread for that ASP.NET Core endpoint, and all of the calls are sequential, are there any performance benefits from using async/await in this code?

Comment: As far as I know asp.net core is no necessarly async by default.  Also by making your call stack async you might be able to not block other calls on long running operations which might get scheduled to use the threadpool and finish on a different thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the benefits of async and await in an ASP.Net MVC Action Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65954639/what-are-the-benefits-of-async-and-await-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action-controller)

Comment: It's worth reading this article, if you haven't already: [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When await CallAllAsync() is called, a Task instance is taken from a Task pool and the code inside CallAllAsync() is run. Lets say the thread for that task is Thread_All. This pauses the parentThread_Get and it will not run until Thread_All is completed.

This is not correct. When `CallAllAsync()` is called, it is executed synchronously until the first `await` is reached. At this point a `Task` is created (there is no pool) that represents the remainder of the method (the "continuation"). Then the task is returned to the caller.

> My question is, since all of this run inside a new thread for that ASP.NET Core endpoint, and all of the calls are sequential, are there any performance benefits from using async/await in this code?

There are no immediate benefits to the current request, since the operations have to happen in series, and each of them takes a certain amount of time to complete. However, using this kind of `async` logic allows the thread to be surrendered to other requests while waiting for these async tasks to complete. This gives your overall application better throughput, and thereby benefits all requests.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. In this context, async/await is a performance gain for the system as a whole, not for the one call. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is correct, but this link goes into a lot more detail on how this works. The short answer is that threads aren't blocking (like I thought). When they are waiting for an async task to complete, the thread goes back into the thread pool, allowing the system to scale much better. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'Task pool'. Tasks are just regular objects, and cost very little to create.

The old method of making async calls usually used callbacks, i.e. something like `SomeDatabaseCallAsync(Action continuation)`, also called continuation passing style. But callbacks are somewhat difficult to use, so it was common to just call synchronous functions in a background thread instead. That is easier to write, but it blocks a thread, and that can be a problem for a web server that needs to serve as many requests as possible.

Tasks and async essentially lets the compiler rewrite all the code to use callbacks behind the scene, while letting you write nice and linear code. while also avoid the overhead of using a thread while waiting for IO.

So, in the context of asp.Net, the main benefit is lower resource usage while doing IO-operations, and hopefully that translates to higher throughput.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET can use the thread for other tasks while waiting for the call to the database to finish.

You have chosen some very good candidate for async calls. And .NET has async save functions for all of them.